# Route planners with route avoidance features

Tags: gps, bikeroutes, maps, navigation

Already asked on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/141455/route-planners-with-route-avoidance-features but may be here is a most adequate place to make the question.

In my quest to search route planners, I didn't find yet one which has the following two features:

1. Avoid a specific point/street. Go from X to Y avoiding passing in Z. As is possible in some to add waypoints, it should also be possible to add nowaypoints via user interaction.
2. Avoid streets with incline superior to X%, where X is input by the user via a text box. It is particularly useful for cycling, to avoid steep inclines going up, and dangerous descents going down.

Does anyone now about some web page which has such features? Tired of searching, didn't find anything.
Thanks.

Comment: Consider asking on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Half of an answer, therefore a comment: Locus Map supports No-Go-Areas, and can display the current elevation profile for the route in the route planner. This would allow you to manually avoid inclines.

Comment: I put no go areas into the Navman when I was team lead back in the early 2000's. Turns out the concept is too complex for the Marketing tyoes to understand so the feature was removed. I think most products have been dumbed down so much features that need more than 2 seconds though to work out how to use them don't exist.

Answer (score 3):

https://brouter.de/brouter-web/

1. Allows you to draw no-go areas.
2. Allows you to specify cost for ascents or descents. I’m not sure it’s possible to tell it to completely avoid streets above a certain incline. You could set the cost very high and set the cutoff to whatever you like. Disadvantage of this approach is that inclines below the cutoff are not considered for routing (i.e. it doesn’t try to avoid shallower inclines anymore).
3. Allows you to specify a plethora of other parameters and can be scripted.